# Get custom view bounds from view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I have `ViewController` with multiple custom views. `CustomView` has an xib called `customView.xib` and is implemented in `CustomView.swift`.

`CustomView` has textfield, and its delegate is implemented in `CustomView.swift`.

When textfield inside `CustomView` in `ViewController` is tapped, delegate method:

```
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        var field = textField as! AddItemTextField
         ViewController?.makeViewOffset(self.bounds.origin.y - 20)          
        }
    }
```

function make offset is implemented in `ViewController` :

```
func makeViewOffset(offset: CGFloat) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.scrollView.contentOffset.y = offset
    })
}
```

So, what I want to achieve:  When some of customViews are tapped on, get their position in my scrollView, and make the scrollView offset to this value, so the view will be visible on the top of scroll.

Where i'm currently at: My bounds are zero, and I cannot pass coordinates to `CustomView.swift`

Any advice?

Comment: you make take a look into convertRect:toView convertRect:fromView methods of the UIView class.

Comment: @teamnorge cool! helps me a lot. if you will suggest an answer - I will apply it asap! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do @teamnorge answer.
Method

```
func convertRect(rect: CGRect, fromView view: UIView?) -> CGRect
```

did all work for me. Thats all.